# Format unformatted time number to readable 24 hour time

Tags: php

My client has entered some start and end dates into our system and I want to be able to format it with PHP.

The values are `930` and `1530`. Processing the `1530` variable is fine but its the `930` that returns false.

Here is my script so far but no success. Error returns `bool(false)` because it can't get a readable time (I believe?)

```
    $time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', $var);
    $format = "H:i";
    $result = $time->format($format);
```

Comment: Pass it through `sprintf()` to 0-pad it: `$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', sprint('%04s', $var));`

Comment: Then fix the data entry so that is it must be entered correctly rather than fixing a mess after the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your initial time format is ambiguous. Assuming that you have time without leading zeros all the time one can do something like this:

```
$var = '930';
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', str_pad($var, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
$format = "H:i";
$result = $time->format($format);
```

Comment: Great stuff and same amount of code lines. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with DateTime for this, split it and join it like this:

```
$var = 1530;
$minutes = substr($var, -2, 2);
$hours = str_replace($minutes, '', $var);
$time = $hours . ':' . $minutes;
```

Then use DateTime on the string:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($time);
$time = $dateTime->format('H:i');
```